# How to insert a record into a table - depending on the total requiredQty from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this row in the database table:

```
ID       requiredQty 
1088         30
```

And another table:

```
ID      orderLineID   bookedInQty
3000       1088           10

3001       1088           10
```

**dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ecd8c83fcda08453481ec6d0ce45947**

**Summary**

Total booked in quantity is total of `20` and `10` remaining for that particular order-line.

**Question**

How can I create an `if` statement to insert a record into the 2nd table, not to exceed table 1 `requiredQty: 30`?

**Example**

If insert `bookedInQty: 11` this means it exceeds `30` because there is an extra `1`. If it exceeds, simply do nothing.

If to insert `bookedInQty: 9` this does not exceeds `30` because the total now equals to `29`. Then insert this record.

**Note**

Without creating any extra tables, I am trying to do it using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses if to check if the sum of the bookedQty and the new value are lower then the required quantity. You can put the code in a stored procedure.

```
create table table1(
  id int NOT NULL,
  requiredQty int
);

create table table2(
  id int NOT NULL,
  orderLineId int,
  bookedInQty int
);

insert into table1(id, requiredQty) VALUES (1088, 30);
insert into table2(id, orderLineId, bookedInQty) 
VALUES
(3000, 1088, 10),
(3001, 1088, 10);

declare @sumQty int, @newQty int, @newOrderLineId int;
select @newOrderLineId = 1088, @newQty = 11; -- change @newQty to 10 or lower

select @sumQty = sum(bookedInQty) from table2 where orderLineId = @newOrderLineId
group by orderLineId;

-- I hardcoded the value of id, it should add 1 to the maximum value or use an identity column
if exists(select * from table1 where id = @newOrderLineId and requiredQty >= @sumQty + @newQty)
  insert table2 (id, orderLineId, bookedInQty) values (3002, @newOrderLineId, @newQty);

select * from table1;
select * from table2;
```

**Dbfiddle demo:**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d800624279381f9bbd71cf51bbc5351a

Comment: Just what I needed! Much appreciated :D